# How do I get a fully-qualified assembly reference if I only have the class name and dll name?

Tags: c#, reflection, compact-framework

I have an application that is running in compact framework 3.5 and has to send information over the wire to a service running the 4.0 framework.  Specifically I am passing information regarding exceptions.  I need to be able to create a new instance of the specified exception using the class name and assembly name.

I'm using Activator.CreateInstance() to create the object and I had planned to use Type.GetType() to get a reference to the corresponding type in the 4.0 framework.  However, I can't quite figure out how to get a Type reference (or fully qualified assembly name to get the type reference) from just the class name and assembly name (since I have no idea of the PublicKeyToken in the 4.0 assembly).

I realize I could cheat and store some of the information in my service for translation, but I'm looking for a fully dynamic lookup of the data that does not involve hard-coding any tokens or version strings.

I am using ProtoBuf-Net to serialize/deserialize my data over the wire.  I was just serializing the Type value itself, but I found this would work for some Exception types and not for others so I have resorted to passing string names of the Class and Assembly since I know a string will be compatible for serialization between the two different framework types/versions.  Specifically the first Exception I ran into that broke when passing the Type value was the System.Net.WebException.

Answer (score 2):

You can just write `System.Web` and Fusion (the CLR's assembly loader) will find a matching assembly for you.
You don't need a version or public-key token.

For example:

```
Type.GetType("System.Web.HttpException, System.Web")
```

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't work for me.  I'm running a test app in .Net 4.0 framework with the following test code `string typeName = "System.Net.WebException, System";
         Type foo = Type.GetType(typeName);` and I get a null value returned into the variable foo.

Comment: @WiredWiz: `Type.GetType("System.Net.WebException, System")` works fine for me in LINQPad.

Comment: Hmm, well I'm not sure what to say other than I'm testing it in a standard 4.0 console application and I get a null value returned.

Comment: What about `Assembly.Load("System")`?

Comment: The "fuslogvw.exe" gave me the following log results: `LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Projects/TypeTester/bin/Debug/System.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Projects/TypeTester/bin/Debug/System/System.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Projects/TypeTester/bin/Debug/System.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Projects/TypeTester/bin/Debug/System/System.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.`

Comment: If I set the property "copy local" on the system reference to true it works just fine as I'd expect from the above log results.